# Javascript static/singelton - this vs _this vs object name

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, this, encapsulation

This is a question about performance and best practice.

Assuming I have a js object that encapsulates a large number of helper methods. The object is being treated as a static class, meaning it is never instantiated and all its methods are basically helper methods.
When using events and jQuery, the object's `this` scope keeps changing, and since it has a fairly large number of methods I am wondering what is best practice - saving `this` into `_this` at the beginning of each method or simply use the object name `MyObject`.

Over the years I've been doing both, when it comes to singelton/static objects, but I figured there must be just 1 best practice and it's about time to adopt the best approach.

My current research shows that the benefits that come with using `_this` instead of directly calling `MyObject` are mainly these two:

- if the object's name changes, `_this` will always work
- May be faster (although haven't seen performance testing results) since the browser stays in the same scope and does not need to find out the scope of `MyObject` every time.

Pros of using `MyObject`:

- Less code to write.
- Garbage collection management? (less variables to assign)
- May be more readable for some developers (where multiple `this` apply)
- Easier to refactor code since `MyObject` will always work

I would like to know if there is a way of globally saving `_this` (only inside the object's scope of course) and avoid assigning it at the beginning of each method. If not - are there other pros/cons that I am missing or is it considered bad practice to call the object name directly.

This is a simplified object for reference (real object has many more methods).

```
    var MyObject = {
       init: function() {

         this.registerEvents();
         //other stuff

       },
       registerEvents: function() {

         this.registerOnSomeEvent();
         //registering more events..
         //...

       },

       registerOnSomeEvent: function() {
          var _this = this;
          jQuery('#someid').click(function() {
             _this.doSomething();//option 1
             MyObject.doSomething();//option 2
          });
       },

       doSomething: function() {
         //doing something...
       }
    }

MyObject.init();
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can encapsulate the entire object in a closure to achieve this without specifiying `_this` on every function:

```
window.MyObject = (function () {
    var self = {
        init: function() {

            self.registerEvents();
            //other stuff

        },
        registerEvents: function() {

            self.registerOnSomeEvent();
            //registering more events..
            //...

        },

        registerOnSomeEvent: function() {
            jQuery('#someid').click(function() {
                self.doSomething();//option 1
                self.doSomething();//option 2
            });
        },

        doSomething: function() {
            //doing something...
        }
    };

    self.init();

    return self;
})();
```

Comment: I like this solution, but since we are again using `self` as the object name, is it really that much different than calling `MyObject` directly? Performance wise I mean

Comment: @Yani Honestly, unless you're accessing that variable 1000s or maybe even millions of times per second it won't really matter. You should optimize for readable and reduction of bugs first.

Comment: @Yani there's no meaningful performance difference. The main advantage over the embedded references to the global variable is that with this approach, `self` cannot change - the global variable might.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you go a very long way of painstakingly emulating something you should do instead.

```
const mySingleton = (function () {
    // Instance stores a reference to the Singleton 
    var instance;
    function init() {
        // Singleton
        // Private methods and variables
        var privateVariable = "Im also private";
        var privateRandomNumber = Math.random();

        return {
            // Public methods and variables
            publicMethod: function () {
                console.log( "The public can see me!" );
            },
            publicProperty: "I am also public",
            get randomNumber() {
                return privateRandomNumber;
            }
         };
         function privateMethod(){
            console.log( "I am private" );
         }

     };
     return {
         // Get the Singleton instance if one exists
         // or create one if it doesn't
         get instance() {
             if ( !instance ) instance = init();
             return instance;
         }
     };   
})();
```

If you don't want to ever use the `this` context, never use inheritance and never have more than one instance just don't write those things as methods on an object, but rather declared, private methods in a [singleton pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript) (which is a revealing module pattern but with only a single instance)

Because as it is you basically make exactly that but you are revealing everything and you spam `this` hundreds and hundreds of times completely without any purpose. `this` **isn't a constant** by design. Don't use it as such.

Comment: You're right, since I come from server side languages, I am trying to mimic a static class behaviour. I wasn't aware it's possible to do what you described +1. However, it doesn't answer how to deal with events and jQuery, where the scope changes?

Comment: the *scope* never changes. using this pattern anything will 100% of the time reference the same thing. the context (*this*) changes, but never the scope. but you don't need to worry about *this* at all, as you won't use it at all in this pattern.

Comment: If you haven't already, check out http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/ .  Its a free online book that goes into a lot of detail on (of course) javaScript design patterns including the Revealing Module pattern.

Comment: @GaryStorey guess what I'm having open right now to check if I said something stupid (turns out I did, the singleton pattern is a bit different, I'll update my answer =)

Comment: @Winchestro thanks for your answer, I've used a slightly different version of this pattern before, but I'm not sure how a private/public method will be called inside a jQuery event. Would you simply use `mySingleton.methodName()` or `instance.methodName()`?

Comment: @Yani well you just pass the reference to the function to the event handler. `yourElement.on("something",yourSingleton.instance.doSomething)` (the way you wrote it it would call the method, but you want to pass it.)