# Is there any difference between (this) and (_this) in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between these 2 statements

`$(this)` and `$(_this)` in jquery.

Comment: One of them uses `this` as a selector, which is a keyword in JavaScript.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)  The other one uses `_this`, which is a normal variable.

Comment: it has nothing to do with jQuery. Probably in your script there is `var _this = this` somewhere in order to store a current scope (that could be change in some context)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722715/javascript-static-singelton-this-vs-this-vs-object-name

Comment: can you tell me an example where we need to store the current scope of that variable?

Comment: @Noel For targeting specific element inside a timeout callback wrapped in any event handler for example, where `this` refers to window object. Or for ajax callback, where `this` refers to jqXHR object. Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` is the current element selector of the context but `$(_this)` is a normal variable selector.

For eg:

```
$('p').on('click',function(){
  var _this = $('div').eq(0);
  console.log($(_this));//first div
  console.log($(this));//clicked element 'p'
});
```

But usually this type of variable is used like this:

```
$('p').on('click',function(){
  var _this = $(this)//clicked element 'p'
  setTimeout(function(){
   //$(this) won't refer to clicked element 'p' because it's out of context
   //$(_this) will refer to clicked element
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why did you use setTimeout() there? So what your saying is that _this is just like any variable name. It could be named "pokemon" and its the same thing as _this? So _this is not something special like how "this" is?